# NodeJS create http request with response

Tags: node.js, express

I learn framework express I tru tun get http method for some url and get body from result, but now only I have this is status 302, I read about corss domain and add allow origin to header but still have redirect with 302
In my example I add logic to routes file, maybe need more pretty organization code, my some Controller with action, I just learning, give me recomendation.

```
host/myapp/routes/parse.js

var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var router = express.Router();

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');  
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  var options = {
    host: 'google.com.ua',
    port: 80,
    path: '/'
  };

  http.get(options, function(res) {
    console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode + "this");
  }).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
  });


  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

and my host/myapp/app.js add

```
//
var parse = require('./routes/parse');
...
app.use('/parse', parse);
//
```

Answer (score 0):

cross-origin HTTP request ([CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)) are only restricted when initiated from within scripts in the front end of your site. Here you are try to load a resource in your via your server so it shouldn't be a problem here. So I guess you should check the log on the server console to find out the problem and also try to use a simple package to fetch your data like [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent)

Answer (score 0):

`http.get` doesn't follow redirects by default.  You'll have to add your own redirection logic, or use a library that supports automatic redirection.

[request](https://github.com/request/request) has built-in support for redirection.

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com.ua', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
  }
})
```

Comment: in `host/myapp/routes/parse.js` ?